# Show values of the last row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to show some values ​​of the last row of a table using a query, I thought I could do it with the MAX() function but it only shows me the maximum values ​​of those two columns, like follows:

```
SELECT max(idInventario) as total,entradaSalida
FROM inventarios;
```

What would be the correct way to do it?, correcting my query or maybe with a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the topmost entry from last like this:

```
SELECT * FROM inventarios WHERE id=(SELECT max(idInventario) FROM inventarios);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row with the highest `idInventario`, you can simply `order by` and `limit`:

```
select idInventario as total, entradaSalida 
from inventarios
order by idInventario desc  -- put the highest "idInventario" on top
limit 1;                    -- keep the first row only
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT idInventario AS total,entradaSalida
FROM inventarios ORDER BY idInventario DESC LIMIT 1;
```